# Getting Element not clickable Error when drag and drop using Actions in Selenium

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

[image]I used the below code for drag and drop purpose with selenium

```
Actions action= new Actions(driver);

Action dragAnddrop = action.clickAndHold(SourceItem)
                        .moveToElement(Destination)
                        .release(Destination)
                        .build();

dragAnddrop.perform();
```

but this code given me the below error.

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: Element is not clickable at point (472, 9041)
```

How can I fix this issue ?

Comment: Please read why [a screenshot of code is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Paste the code and properly format it instead.

Comment: Have you already googled the error message and tried some of the suggestions presented? If you haven't, go do that first then come back with your edited code and results.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have to wait for `ElementIsClickable` from expected conditions, like this:

```
WebDriverWait wdWait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
wdWait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(element));
```

Then execute your the code from your `Action`.

**EDIT**

You also do not need a second variable for `Action` - the `dragAnddrop`. The `Java` implementation of `perform()` does the `build()` as well, so this can also be skipped.

Try this:

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
    .until(ExpectedConditions
        .elementToBeClickable(SourceItem));

new Actions(driver)
    .dragAndDrop(SourceItem, Destination)
    .perform();
```

I completely forgot there is a specific method for this. You might need to include the mentioned before `moveToElement()` but this code should work as it is.

Comment: Hi Moro thanks for the response, it also does not work. That thing I applied for both of the element, for even that it does not work as well

Comment: I will edit my answer as I see a couple more flaws, but please share your debug log.

Comment: Hi Moro, I have attached the log with my post by editing it. The same issue came with your new suggestion as well.